# Python Turtle Move Through List of Coordinates on Timer

Tags: python, timer, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to get Python Turtle to move through a list of coordinates using a timer.There are probably many ways to do this, but with my current attempt, the program just hangs. Could someone explain why please?

```
import turtle

path = [(0, 0), (10, 10), (10, 20), (30, 40)]
bob = turtle.Turtle("square")

def do_path(a_list):
    x, y = a_list[0]
    bob.goto(x, y)
    while len(a_list) > 0:
        turtle.ontimer(lambda: do_path(a_list[1:]), 500)

do_path(path)
turtle.done()
```

Using a global variable doesn't seem to help either:

```
import turtle

path = [(0, 0), (10, 10), (10, 20), (30, 40)]
bob = turtle.Turtle("square")

def do_path():
    global path
    x, y = path.pop(0)
    bob.goto(x, y)
    while len(path) > 0:
        turtle.ontimer(lambda: do_path(path), 500)

do_path()
turtle.done()
```

Comment: You have a while loop with a condition that's always true (`len(a_list) > 0`), so your program enters an infinite loop.

Comment: So `lambda: do_path(a_list[1:])` doesn't modify `a_list`? In a recursive function call it would no?

Comment: No, it will just call `do_path` with a reference to the original list. If you want a recursive solution, you need to think of two cases: `len(a_list) > 0` and `len(a_list) == 0`. That being said, recursion is a bit of an overkill here, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That recursive call in a while loop looks scary to me - the while loop will never end for all depths of the recursion where `len(a_list) != 0`. More like this maybe?

```
import turtle

coordinates = [
    (0, 0),
    (10, 10),
    (10, 20),
    (30, 40)
]

coordinates_iter = iter(coordinates)

t = turtle.Turtle("square")

def go_to_next_coord():
    try:
        next_coord = next(coordinates_iter)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    t.goto(next_coord)
    turtle.ontimer(go_to_next_coord, 500)

go_to_next_coord()
turtle.done()
```

> So lambda: do_path(a_list[1:]) doesn't modify a_list? In a recursive
>   function call it would no?

Definitely not! You're just slicing `a_list` and passing that (completely independent) list to `do_path` as an argument. `a_list` from the very first recursion will not have changed in size, so the while loop happly hangs as your `do_path` waits to finish.

EDIT - on the topic of whether or not it's really "recursion":

```
import turtle

def foo(depth):
    print(f"Starting depth {depth}")
    if depth != 5:
        turtle.ontimer(lambda: foo(depth+1), 1000)
    print(f"Ending depth {depth}")

foo(0)
```

Output:

```
Starting depth 0
Ending depth 0
Starting depth 1
Ending depth 1
Starting depth 2
Ending depth 2
Starting depth 3
Ending depth 3
Starting depth 4
Ending depth 4
Starting depth 5
Ending depth 5
```

Looks like it's technically not strictly recursive at all! It seems turtle has a way of scheduling these callbacks. The output you can expect to see in a recursive setup would have looked like this:

```
Starting depth 0
Starting depth 1
Starting depth 2
Starting depth 3
Starting depth 4
Starting depth 5
Ending depth 5
Ending depth 4
Ending depth 3
Ending depth 2
Ending depth 1
Ending depth 0
```

However, the issue you're having doesn't have anything to do with recursion or turtle in general. To be precise, it has to do with a misunderstanding of the call-stack and/or potentially list slicing. Take a look at this example code:

```
def do_it(depth, items):
    length = len(items)
    print(f"I'm recursion depth {depth}, I see {length} item(s).")
    if depth != 5: #arbitrary base case:
        new_items = items[1:]
        print(f"Depth {depth} - items: {items}")
        print(f"Depth {depth} - new_items: {new_items}")
        do_it(depth+1, new_items)
    print(f"Depth {depth} is ending now, length is {length} and items is {items}")

do_it(0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Output:

```
I'm recursion depth 0, I see 5 item(s).
Depth 0 - items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Depth 0 - new_items: [2, 3, 4, 5]
I'm recursion depth 1, I see 4 item(s).
Depth 1 - items: [2, 3, 4, 5]
Depth 1 - new_items: [3, 4, 5]
I'm recursion depth 2, I see 3 item(s).
Depth 2 - items: [3, 4, 5]
Depth 2 - new_items: [4, 5]
I'm recursion depth 3, I see 2 item(s).
Depth 3 - items: [4, 5]
Depth 3 - new_items: [5]
I'm recursion depth 4, I see 1 item(s).
Depth 4 - items: [5]
Depth 4 - new_items: []
I'm recursion depth 5, I see 0 item(s).
Depth 5 is ending now, length is 0 and items is []
Depth 4 is ending now, length is 1 and items is [5]
Depth 3 is ending now, length is 2 and items is [4, 5]
Depth 2 is ending now, length is 3 and items is [3, 4, 5]
Depth 1 is ending now, length is 4 and items is [2, 3, 4, 5]
Depth 0 is ending now, length is 5 and items is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

I know the output is a bit dense to follow, but hopefully it should demonstrate a misconception you seem to be having. Just because you call a new function (or the same function in the case of recursion) within a function, doesn't mean that the function you're "leaving" ends or terminates. The function you left is waiting on the call-stack until the function you went to terminates, and then execution comes back to the calling-function. All I'm really trying to highlight here is that the different "depths" (functions sitting on the call-stack) see different things. The example I used here is recursive, but the same thing applies in your non-recursive case. Just because you called `do_path` inside of `do_path` doesn't mean that the old `do_path` just suddenly goes away. It's waiting for the inner, most recent invokation of `do_path` to finish until it can finish.

Comment: OK, but I thought a new list would be passed to each call, with a reduced size.

Comment: That is true, but remember, the very first call you made to `do_path` stays on the call stack until it terminates. As far as the very first call (the first recursion depth) is concerned, `a_list` has not changed in size at all, which means the while loop (in the first recursion depth) will not terminate, and so the call stack cannot unwind. This is also true for all other calls (recursion depths) to `do_path` where the local copy of whatever `a_list` happens to be (local to that recursion depth) has more than zero elements.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit out of my depth here. I learned recently that in JaveScript, `setTimeOut` can LOOK recursive when calling the same function that contains it, but does not behave that way. Does Python's `turtle.ontimer()` avoid recursion in this situation as well?

Comment: @Robin Andrews That's a good question. I've edited my post, take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the detailed info.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to fix this but retain the flavor of your original approach, to tidy it up, I'd use a `partial()` from functools instead of a `lambda` (along with an `update_wrapper()` to make it palatable to `ontimer()`).  I'd also remove the assumption that the path starts at `(0, 0)` and start with the pen up, dropping it after moving to the first coordinate:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from functools import partial, update_wrapper

path = [ \
    (100, 180), (90, 170), (95, 150), (80, 135), (65, 145), \
    (55, 140), (70, 125), (65, 105), (75, 85), (60, 70), \
    (70, 60), (80, 75), (100, 65), (120, 75), (130, 60), \
    (140, 70), (125, 85), (135, 105), (130, 125), (145, 140), \
    (135, 145), (120, 135), (105, 150), (110, 170), (100, 180), \
]

def do_path(a_list):
    position, *rest = a_list

    bob.setposition(position)
    bob.pendown()

    if rest:
        wrapper = partial(do_path, rest)
        update_wrapper(wrapper, do_path)
        screen.ontimer(wrapper, 500)
    else:
        bob.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()

bob = Turtle('square')
bob.penup()

do_path(path)

screen.exitonclick()
```